# Use Jest to mock "import *"

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I have a TypeScript source file that has the following import:

```
// myCode.ts
import * as x from 'dep';
... 
export class myClass {
   ...
}
```

where `dep` is a Node package that's included as part of the npm install.  `myCode.ts` is a simple class that just has three methods.  I would like to mock the entire `myClass` from inside a Jest test script that is written to test another class, `myMainClass`.

The problem I'm having is that the `dep` code is running some initialization that I can't seem to bypass.  The initialization code fails outside the "real" environment so I simply want to bypass this for test purposes.  No matter what I try I get an error that looks something like this:

```
  Test suite failed to run

    Dynamic Linking Error: ... error text ...

      5 | // myCode.js
    > 6 | import * as x from 'dep';
        | ^
```

Again, the error is expected since I don't have these libraries locally (and don't want them for  unit testing).

I was hoping I could add a simple mock statement (e.g., `jest.mock('myClass')`, or something similar, that would bypass anything to do with `myClass`.  That way the code causing the link error would not be executed.

I'm fairly new to using Jest.  Hopefully, this is a simple ask and I'm just missing the obvious.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: What's the *"error text"* about? You can create a file `dep.js` inside `__mocks__` directory to have Jest pick that file instead of the real module, but you have to be careful on what is being called from `dep` inside `myClass` and that should also be mocked out.

Comment: In this case the `dep` Node package is a wrapper for some native binaries that aren't easy to run in my development environment (MacOS).  For UT of my code I don't really need (or want) to run the native code.  The problem comes in when the import triggers whatever initialization the `dep` package does that tries to load the native code.  Even though I'm mocking the class that uses this package this initialization still gets executed and causes the test case to fail.  Make sense?

Comment: You don't have to mock `myClass`, just `dep`. If you properly mock `dep`, when it imports inside `myCode.ts` it won't try to import anything other than the `dep.js` inside the `__mock__` directory. You don't have to write any code regarding dep, just mock the functions that are being called from `myClass`. For example, if `dep` exports a function named `depNativeFn` with some native code, the mock inside `__mocks__/dep.js` should have `const dep =  {}; dep.depNativeFn = jest.fn(); export default dep;` or something very similar. Thus Jest won't try to import `dep`, but it will use that file.

Comment: It would be easier to provide a working solution if you've had a reproducible example in a Github repo or a Codesandbox.